Pattern-Based "Warning / Error" Generator for Visual Studio? (C#)
When working with multiple devs, there are sometimes soft-constraints that need to be obeyed for proper functionality.
In Eclipse / Java, we use a "pattern based" project validator to validate some of of these soft-constraints and display a warning / error if a violation is found.
This generator has a quite simple feature to validate stuff, by just definining a Regex-Pattern - and upon a positive Match, a predefined Warning / Error is displayed, so something like
 DBContext\.Save() | Error | .Save() should not be used for production purpose. Use .SaveAndAudit() instead.

Is there such a tiny helper tool for Visual Studio available as well? Or even builtin functionality in VS? Couldn't find anything like that (without digging too deep into multiple Code Analyzer Frameworks)

Refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/analyzers/Analyzer%20Actions%20Semantics.md

You need to use roslyn analyzer.
Please follow to the tutorial to create a Analyzer with code fix (.NET Standard) project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix
And modify the code:

Set  DiagnosticSeverity Warning Or Error .
private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

Add syntax check action：
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
         context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
     }

     private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
     {
         var invocationExpr = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

         // Check if the invocation is for a method named "Save"
         if (invocationExpr.Expression is MemberAccessExpressionSyntax memberAccess &&
             memberAccess.Name.Identifier.Text == "Save")
         {
             var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocationExpr.GetLocation());
             context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
         }
     }



Below  is  Unit Test project:
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VerifyCS = Analyzer1.Test.CSharpCodeFixVerifier<
    Analyzer1.Analyzer1Analyzer,
    Analyzer1.Analyzer1CodeFixProvider>;
namespace Analyzer1.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Analyzer1UnitTest
    {
        //No diagnostics expected to show up
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            var test = @"
    using System;
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class MyClass
        {
            public void Save() { }
        }
        class AnotherClass
        {
            public void Save1() { }
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var myClass = new MyClass();
                myClass.Save();
                var anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
                anotherClass.Save1();
            }
        }
    }";
            await VerifyCS.VerifyAnalyzerAsync(test);
        }
    }
}

3.Comment the  code snippet in the project CodeFixes
    // Register a code action that will invoke the fix.
    //context.RegisterCodeFix(
    //    CodeAction.Create(
    //        title: CodeFixResources.CodeFixTitle,
    //        createChangedSolution: c => MakeUppercaseAsync(context.Document, declaration, c),
    //        equivalenceKey: nameof(CodeFixResources.CodeFixTitle)),
    //    diagnostic);



Is your problem being solved? It is hoped that you can give any feedback. @dognose
